# How to find connection between two uers in django rest?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have one Follower system and here I want to check those are following to me,we have a mutual connection or not. If they are following to me and I'm not following to them, I want to set in frontend follow back. Inside the views, I'm fetching the data and sending them to serializer but I don't, How I can check it?
My models and views are in below:

models.py

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE,related_name = 'following')
    followee = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE,related_name = 'followers')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, null = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, null = True)
    class Meta:
       unique_together = ("follower", "followee")
       ordering  = ('-created_at',)
```

views.py:

```
class FollowerAPIView(APIView,PaginationHandlerMixin):
    pagination_class = BasicPagination
    serializer_class = UserFollowerSerializer
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        follower_qs = Follow.objects.filter(followee = request.user).select_related('follower')
        page = self.paginate_queryset(follower_qs)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_paginated_response(self.serializer_class(page, many=True).data)
        else:
            serializer = self.serializer_class(follower_qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve via handling it in serializer. There is a parameter named `context` in serialier and use that to check the required condition as follow:

```
UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    follow_back = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (<user_model_fields>, 'follow_back')

    # have a function here to decide the value of follow back

    def get_follow_back(self, obj):
        user_id = self.context.get('user_id', None) 
        # This is the user id of person fetching the user profile of other person
        if user_id is not None:
            i_follow_user = Follow.objects.filter(follower=obj.id, followee=user_id).first()
            user_follow_me = Follow.objects.filter(followee=obj.id, follower=user_id).first()
            return i_follow_user is None and user_follow_me is not None
        return False
```

So, now when you serialize other person's profile using this serializer you have to pass your user id into the serializer as follow:

```
UserProfileSerializer(other_user_instance, context={'user_id': request.user.id})
```

here request.user is the authenticated user or the user fetching the other person's profile.